# How to display xml-string using DataSet in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

What should i use in aspx in order to display the xml-string inside a gridview?

`Data` is the xml-string :

```
<Study>
      <DocTypes>
        <DocType>
          <Name>doctype1</Name>
          <Evaluate>false</Evaluate>
        </DocType>
        <DocType>
          <Name>doctype2</Name>
          <Evaluate>true</Evaluate>
        </DocType>
      </DocTypes>
      <DocumentView>true</DocumentView>
      <ColumnarView>true</ColumnarView>
</Study>
```

in code behind display.aspx.cs i use XmlTextReader and then bind the GridView with the DataSet:

```
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(Data);
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xtr);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

What should i writte in display.aspx?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
 <Column> ???? </Column>
```

**EDIT**  I found out using dataset.Tables[number] i can display the content, but i also get some strange columns with _ID. How can i remove the _ID columns?

**EDIT** Right now i can't see the DocTypes inside the DataSet. What should i use to display them too?

**EDIT** if i change the number of dataset.Tables[number] i get Doctypes and DocTypePermissions but how to merge the tables???

Comment: What all data do you want to show in the GridView, with this current example of XML string, you can't load whole XML in GridView

Comment: I wanted to load everything. Is DataSet the wrong approach for that?

Comment: @Georg - the columns with _Id are for relationship.In Dataset you will have Doctypes table parent to Doctype table. If you remove the relationship and save the xml, Doctype nodes will be appended to Study rather than Doctypes node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the xml into dataset, ite creates 3 tables in the dataset:

1. Study
2. DocTypes and
3. DocType

It also creates [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx). This relation is based on columns with hidden [ColumnMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping.aspx) and as far I know, naming convention for this field is ParentTable FieldName_Id. If you want to save data back to XML, you will need this field.

To hide this field in Gridview I would set AutoGenerateColumns= "false" and populate only the fields I need in the grid. If you want to set it to true, in GridView's RowDataBound event you have to set visibility of this cell to false: `e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;`

Now you know the table names, their field names, you can easily bind them to GridView. Bind the Gridview to "DocType" table as shown in the example.

Answer to your 3rd EDIT, You don't need to merge the tables. You are binding the repeating rows to GridView, and just use label or textbox or checkbox to display non repeating row, i.e. DocumentView and ColumnarView.

You can call a method in PageLoad like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
           BindData();
      }
 }
```

Ans in your BindData() method may look like:

```
private void BindData()
{
    DataSet ds = LoadXml();
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["DocType"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    DataRow r = ds.Tables["Study"].Rows[0];
    chkDocumentView.Checked = bool.Parse(r[1].ToString());
    chkColumnarView.Checked = bool.Parse(r[2].ToString());
}
```

Now, the method to read xml string:

```
private DataSet LoadXml() 
{
    string Data = @"<Study>
                        <DocTypes>
                        <DocType>
                            <Name>doctype1</Name>
                            <Evaluate>false</Evaluate>
                        </DocType>
                        <DocType>
                            <Name>doctype2</Name>
                            <Evaluate>true</Evaluate>
                        </DocType>
                        </DocTypes>
                        <DocumentView>true</DocumentView>
                        <ColumnarView>true</ColumnarView>
                </Study>";

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(Data);
    XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xtr);

    return ds;           
}
```

And the markup for GridView and checkboxes:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />  
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox Text="Evaluate" runat="server" Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("Evaluate").ToString())%>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDocumentView" Text="DocumentView" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumnarView" Text="ColumnarView" runat="server"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
  StringReader sr = new StringReader(data);
  XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ds.ReadXml(xtr);
  ds.Merge(ds, true);
  GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
  GridView1.DataBind();
```

Also please go through this link,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317662

Comment: No need to add columns in aspx page.